# Animation of a teardrop with Geometry Nodes and Simulation Node

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I'm trying to make the fall off a tear.
I use geometry nodes with simulation nodes.
What I want is that the first hundred frames the tear drops little by little.
And from frame 101 the tear falls fast.
Instead, the tear falls slowly all the time.

[image]

My Geometry Nodes

[image]

Where is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: pos will never be increased/changed...so the switch will always be false. I think what you might want to compare is the "real" position because this would change. But honestly if you want it to be dependent on frame, you should also work with scene time - not with values from a position or an offset

Comment: i am not sure whether you know a programming language - if yes, this might help: a named attribute is nothing else then a variable in a programming language. You can read or set(change) it. But you never change the POS value.

Comment: Thanks Chris your comments are very usefull. I will change the way I do. I will store the inicial position of the tear and compare it to the actual position. If the lenght between the two vectors is greater than X I will move the tear quickly otherwise I will move the tear slowly.